# On Ergodicity of the product of two Ergodic transformations

Tags: probability, ergodic-theory

I was recently reading some textbooks and topics in Ergodic theory that I found this fascinating result which I couldn't prove completely:

> Suppose that $T$ and $S$ are two Ergodic transformations.  Show that $T*S$ is Ergodic if and only if the only common eigenvalue of both $T$ and $S$ is $1$.

In the above, $T*S$ denotes the product of the two transformations.

Comment: I think you need the spaces on which $T$ and $S$ operate to be restricted in size, based on the abstract for this paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-186-00/S0002-9947-1973-0328021-6/S0002-9947-1973-0328021-6.pdf

For instance, both finite would suffice.